# Laravel spatie sitemap generate without modified date, priority and changefrequency

Tags: php, laravel

I have a problem with this package: https://github.com/spatie/laravel-sitemap.

I have a code:

```
$sitemap_basic = Sitemap::create()
                ->add(
                    Url::create(env('APP_URL') . '/')
                        ->setLastModificationDate('')
                        ->setChangeFrequency('')
                        ->setPriority('')
                        );
```

When I save sitemap with empty params I get errors:

```
Expected type 'DateTime'. Found 'string'
Expected type 'DateTime'. Found 'string'
```

`setChangeFrequency` I can set empty in sitemap. But `setPriority`, `setLastModificationDate` - not. How I can set empty this params?

Answer (score 0):

```php
$sitemap_basic = Sitemap::create()->add(Url::create(env('APP_URL') . '/'));
```

The `setLastModificationDate` method [has](https://github.com/spatie/laravel-sitemap/blob/master/src/Tags/Url.php#L64) a not null `DateTime` parameter hinted.

The `setPriority` method [has](https://github.com/spatie/laravel-sitemap/blob/master/src/Tags/Url.php#L88) a not null `float` parameter hinted.

If you don't want to set those values don't call those setters.

Also for what I've seen in the documentation and the source code, `setChangeFrequency` is meant to be called with some specific strings [as you can see here](https://github.com/spatie/laravel-sitemap/blob/master/src/Tags/Url.php#L10).

Comment: I get default params of constructor of URL class: https://github.com/spatie/laravel-sitemap/blob/master/src/Tags/Url.php

Comment: That URL class is specifically designed for always having those attributes set, you won't be able to get the result by using it as it is.

Comment: Also setting those values to `null` was already requested and closed, you can track de issue here: https://github.com/spatie/laravel-sitemap/issues/220